# Can any infinite set be written as the union of finite sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While working on a problem, I was wondering about the following: Is it  possible to write any infinite set as union of finite sets or not ?

Comment: Congrats @Stefan: for beating Asaf to the punch for changing a (set-theory) tag to (elementary-set-theory) :P

Comment: @EricStucky Well, that's one lifetime achievement taken care of :P

Comment: Hahaha @EricStucky/Stefan is this a thing now? :)

Comment: If we could, why bother with having an axiom to define an infinite set?

Comment: @JDlugosz: If there aren't any infinite sets, then it's automatically true that every infinite set can be written as a union of finite sets.

Answer (score 31):

Sure, it's possible. Let $X$ be *any* set. Then
$$
X = \bigcup_{x \in X} \{x \}.
$$
So any set is a union of singletons (except maybe for the empty set - dependent on how you'd interpret the above formula in this case).

Comment: Is that also true even for uncountable infinite set ?

Comment: @Sara Yup! Nothing different there. "$\bigcup_{x\in X}A_x$" always means "The set of things which are in some $A_x$ (with $x\in X$)", so "$\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$" always means "$X$."

Comment: @Stefan The empty union is empty, so that still works. ($\bigcup_{x\in X}A_x=\{y: \exists x\in X(y\in A_x)\}$, so if $X$ is empty $\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$ is just $\emptyset$.)

Comment: @Noah Yes, I'm aware ;) But I also know that some mathematicians feel uneasy about 'the empty union' much like they feel uneasy about 'the empty function'.

Comment: @Stefan: Some mathematicians feel uneasy by anything empty, it is called fear of the void. This is in large part because teaching systematically avoids talking about them for fear of making the audience uneasy. Think of empty matrices in linear algebra, where (sub)spaces of dimension $0$ (which aren't even empty) are of eminent importance. In the current case there is no reason to shy away from the empty union: the union of elements of any set exists. What is problematic is the empty _intersection_, and it is good to be aware of that. But this difficulty is not contagious.

Comment: Is the [axiom of inifinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity) required to define the union of an infinite number of sets?

Comment: @chepner: In ZFC, if you don't have the axiom of infinity then you can't even prove the existence of an infinite set, and so from where can you even get an infinite number of sets?

Comment: @chepner In ZFC there actually is no indexed union $\bigcup_i A_i$, but only the union of a set of sets $\bigcup X$ (simply put, "flattening" the sets by removing the inner braces (or, non-simply put, monadic join :-P)). So, you need an infinite $X$ beforehand if you want to do an infinite union, and crafting that one indeed requires the axiom of infinity.

Comment: Thanks; I'm not even sure why I asked that now.

Comment: What about the set of all sets?

Comment: @chi: But the question only asked if something was true for *any* infinite set, and for that you don't need to prove that infinite sets exist; in ZFC minus Infinity, you have models without infinite sets, but in those models the claim is vacuously true, and models with infinite sets, which are then the same you get with full ZFC. So you do *not* need the axiom of infinity. Indeed, you just need three axioms: Extensionality (without which you'd not be able to tell whether the union is the same set), Union (obviously) and Replacement (to get from $S$ to $\{\{x\}:x\in S\}$.

Comment: @celtschk Fully agreed. But chepner asked about "the union of an infinite number of sets" without stating precisely whether we know that that infinite class of sets is actually a set (of sets). For indexed families, we can't (in general) have $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ a set unless we know $I$ is a set (and the $A_i$ as well).

Comment: @BradThomas There *isn't* a set of all sets . . .